# How can I associate collectionView cell with specific attributes in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, bundle, xcode8

So I'm trying to make a gallery app.

First in the app there is a collectionView controller that has a collection View.

The collectionView prototype cell has a UIImageView

There is also a detail View Controller with a larger imageView

Basically in the app, the user can scroll through icons of locations and look at the larger image by clicking on one.

I've gathered my icon images via the bundle path and used them with my UIImageView for the cell.

But I do not know how to make the image of the detailViewController correspond to the cell that was clicked as they are both different images.

How can I solve this? Do I use a struct or class with the imageName as an attribute? Or something else?

Comment: Have two arrays with collectionview image names and detailsview image names use this delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` u will get indexpath.row as selected item and with search in detailsview array for indexpath.row and display the corresponding image. If u still didn't get comment below for a detailed explanation

Comment: If you use imageview in custom cell , then get that selected cell [cell.imageView.image]  and store it global variable as UIImage.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. This will require for both arrays to be in the same order and length?

Comment: if you get your selected cell image in didSelectItemAtIndexPath , that easy way to store  var  selectedPhoto :UIImage = UIImage() as a global. and setthis   selectedPhoto.image = cell.image . use this in your secondViewConroler.

Comment: I need the detailViewController to have a different image